# Minkowski sum of bounded set and unit disk is measurable

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is Problem 263 in *Theorems and Problems in Functional Analysis*.

> Let $A$ be any bounded set in the plane and $B$ the unit disk
>   $x^2+y^2<1$. Prove that for any positive numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$
>   the set $\alpha A+\beta B$ is Lebesgue-measurable, and if $A$ is
>   convex, then 
>   $$\mu(\alpha A+\beta B) = S\alpha^2 + L\alpha\beta + \pi\beta^2.$$
>   What is the meaning of the coefficients $S$ and $L$?

The hint tells that $S=\mu(A)$ and $L$ is the perimeter of $A$. I have no idea how to prove it, but I think the conclusion can be extended to higher dimensions. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Obviously, you forgot something: $A$ should be measurable, too. If $A$ is convex, that's true, it's a special case of the Steiner formula, indeed.

Comment: @ProfessorVector The part of the problem where $A$ isn't yet assumed to be convex is OK even if $A$ isn't measurable. The point is that $\alpha A+\beta B$ is open and therefore measurable.

Comment: @Andreas Blass Oh, yes, you're right, of course.